How to better manage two columns of toggle switches in a table?
In this table, I have two columns of toggle switches, two toggles for each cell - I need to be able to decide if an email is sent at the start/finish of an alert, same with sms. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing something like that? The way it is now doesn't feel right, but I'm out of ideas

Please add an image instead of a link. Links will break eventually.

You can use checks instead of toggles. As you mentioned it feels odd visually when you have plenty of toggles in the same area. You're option completes the functionality however I believe that you want to solve your design aesthetics.
If your toggles have micro-animations that could impact the loading of your page so you need to check on that to define the best option.
If you use checks you have the same functionality with better aesthetic. Here's an option.

It is basically the same but with other component.
‍
